# jQuery PageSlide: .css function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide

**Hi everybody!**

I use this plugin: *PageSlide* and this is the code of *jquery.pageslide.js*:

```
(function($) {
  var $body = $("body"),
    $pageslide = $("#pageslide");
  var
    _sliding = false,
    _lastCaller;
  if ($pageslide.length == 0) {
    $pageslide = $("<div />").attr("id", "pageslide").css("display", "none").appendTo($("body"));
  }

  function
  _load(url, useIframe) {
    if (url.indexOf("#") === 0) {
      $(url).clone(true).appendTo($pageslide.empty()).show();
    } else {
      if (useIframe) {
        var
          iframe = $("<iframe
 />").attr({
            src: url,
            frameborder: 0,
            hspace: 0
          }).css({
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
          });
        $pageslide.html(iframe);
      } else {
        $pageslide.load(url);
      }
      $pageslide.data("localEl", false);
    }
  }

  function
  _start(direction, speed) {
    var slideWidth = $pageslide.outerWidth(true),
      bodyAnimateIn = {},
      slideAnimateIn = {};
    if ($pageslide.is(":visible") || _sliding) {
      return;
    }
    _sliding = true;
    switch (direction) {
      case "left":
        $pageslide.css({
          left: "auto",
          right: "-" + slideWidth + "px"
        });
        bodyAnimateIn["margin-left"] = "-=" + slideWidth;
        slideAnimateIn["right"] = "+=" + slideWidth;
        break;
      default:
        $pageslide.css({
          left: "-" + slideWidth + "px",
          right: "auto"
        });
        bodyAnimateIn["margin-left"] = "+=" + slideWidth;
        slideAnimateIn["left"] = "+=" + slideWidth;
        break;
    }
    $body.animate(bodyAnimateIn, speed);
    $pageslide.show().animate(slideAnimateIn, speed, function() {
      _sliding = false;
    });
  }
  $.fn.pageslide = function(options) {
    var
      $elements = this;
    $elements.click(function(e) {
      var
        $self = $(this),
        settings = $.extend({
          href: $self.attr("href")
        }, options);
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      if ($pageslide.is(":visible") && $self[0] == _lastCaller) {
        $.pageslide.close();
      } else {
        $.pageslide(settings);
        _lastCaller = $self[0];
      }
    });
  };
  $.fn.pageslide.defaults = {
    speed: 200,
    direction: "right",
    modal: false,
    iframe: true,
    href: null
  };
  $.pageslide = function(options) {
    var
      settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.pageslide.defaults, options);
    if ($pageslide.is(":visible") && $pageslide.data("direction") != settings.direction) {
      $.pageslide.close(function() {
        _load(settings.href, settings.iframe);
        _start(settings.direction, settings.speed);
      });
    } else {
      _load(settings.href, settings.iframe);
      if ($pageslide.is(":hidden")) {
        _start(settings.direction, settings.speed);
      }
    }
    $pageslide.data(settings);
  };
  $.pageslide.close = function(callback) {
    var
      $pageslide = $("#pageslide"),
      slideWidth = $pageslide.outerWidth(true),
      speed = $pageslide.data("speed"),
      bodyAnimateIn = {},
      slideAnimateIn = {};
    if ($pageslide.is(":hidden") || _sliding) {
      return;
    }
    _sliding = true;
    switch ($pageslide.data("direction")) {
      case "left":
        bodyAnimateIn["margin-left"] = "+=" + slideWidth;
        slideAnimateIn["right"] = "-=" + slideWidth;
        break;
      default:
        bodyAnimateIn["margin-left"] = "-=" + slideWidth;
        slideAnimateIn["left"] = "-=" + slideWidth;
        break;
    }
    $pageslide.animate(slideAnimateIn, speed);
    $body.animate(bodyAnimateIn, speed, function() {
      $pageslide.hide();
      _sliding = false;
      if (typeof callback != "undefined") {
        callback();
      }
    });
  };
  $pageslide.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).bind("click
 keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.type == "keyup" && e.keyCode != 27) {
      return;
    }
    if ($pageslide.is(":visible") && !$pageslide.data("modal")) {
      $.pageslide.close();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**I need one more function:**
when PageSlide is active - so the left menu opened - a width of [content] `div` changes to `600px` and when inactive, changes back to the original 1200px.

I think the good code is: `$('#content').css('width', '600px');`, but I don't know where to place it. I don't know much the JavaScript.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the _start() function is what is called to adjust the $pageslide element. Try adding your additional changes to that function.

```js
 _start(direction, speed) {
    var slideWidth = $pageslide.outerWidth(true),
      bodyAnimateIn = {},
      slideAnimateIn = {},
      //may want to declare this somewhere else so its not fetched every time from the dom
      $content = $('#content');
    if ($pageslide.is(":visible") || _sliding) {
      return;
    }
    _sliding = true;
    switch (direction) {
      case "left":
        $pageslide.css({
          left: "auto",
          right: "-" + slideWidth + "px"
        });
        bodyAnimateIn["margin-left"] = "-=" + slideWidth;
        slideAnimateIn["right"] = "+=" + slideWidth;
        // Looks like the default for direction is set to 'right', so this would be when its closing
        $content.css({
          width: '1200px'
        })
        break;
      default:
        $pageslide.css({
          left: "-" + slideWidth + "px",
          right: "auto"
        });
        bodyAnimateIn["margin-left"] = "+=" + slideWidth;
        slideAnimateIn["left"] = "+=" + slideWidth;
        //this should be when its opening. If not, just switch the two inserted statements.
         $content.css({
          width: '600px'
        })
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The shorting to 600px is Ok, but back to the original size isn't :(